# what is the most cited grammar book?

Tags: grammar

I know OED is the most cited vocabulary book, then what is the most cited grammar book? I think it’s The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. I made this question because I have to cite the grammar book...I know it’s off-topic but I’m really desperate.

Comment: Yes, the prize-winning CGEL is the most comprehensive and accurate grammar book ever written, and is probably the go-to grammar for most grammarians.

Comment: There is no grammar book that has the same renown among laypeople that the OED has. Most English speakers have heard of the OED (though most also don't understand the distinction between the actual OED and various smaller Oxford dictionaries), whereas most couldn't name a single grammar book. But you're right, CGEL is a comprehensive and highly regarded work.

Comment: The OED is not a grammar, but a dictionary.You can't learn grammar from it.

Comment: I keep it in mind thank you thank you

Comment: I agree, BillJ. I was merely commenting on the fact that the OP was asking about the counterpart or equivalent to the OED.